# slack - get team URL from webhooks

Tags: slack, slack-api

Is it possible to either get the team `URL` from a slack webhook or get the team `URL` from a channel/user `ID`?

For example, from the hook:

https://hooks.slack.com/service/foobar-hook get the team `URL` in order to do other things with slack `API`. The main idea is to minimize code/configuration. You pass the webhooks and you're done, instead of passing the webhook and also de team `URL`.

And the same for a channel id:

Is it possible from the channel ID `HNAs319A` get the team `URL`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Webhook URLs have no relation to the slack URL. They do contain the team ID though.

Example for team with ID T1234567: 
`https://hooks.slack.com/services/T1234567/XXX/YYY`

Channel IDs are only unique within a team, so its not possible to extract the slack URL from it.

You can however get the slack URL if you have a valid access token with the API method [`auth.test`](https://api.slack.com/methods/auth.test). Maybe that helps solve your problem.

Here is an response example for that method (from the documentation):

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "url": "https:\/\/myteam.slack.com\/",
    "team": "My Team",
    "user": "cal",
    "team_id": "T12345",
    "user_id": "U12345"
}
```

Comment: That is great. I indeed have a token. This is useful!